# Calculate similarity of weighted trees

Tags: tree, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

The structure of my tree is simple, the depth is two, each child node is the direct child of the root, and each node has a weight except the root. Is there a good way to measure the similarity of two trees?
Here is the original question:
Suppose you have a data list about the books that you have read. The list contains keys and values like a hashtable. The keys are the book categories, and the values are the amount of books that you have read under the current category. So every person has this data list, I want to compare the similarity of two users based on this data list. I know the collaborative-iltering can do this, but I am trying this way and compare it with cf.
So I treat the data list as a weighted tree. The categories are the child nodes, the weight of each child node is the times that this category appears in user's books.
The similarity is similar with the similarity of two users in collaborative iltering. It's a number.

Comment: Chances are that if you can articulate the definition of "similar", the algorithm will pop out. What is your definition of similarity? Is it a boolean predicate, or a continuous measure? As you have it, our question is likely to get close-voted: *Not a Real Question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Comment: @Kaz Thanks for your reminding, I'll pay attention to it.

Comment: If the tree has depth two, and the root has no weight, how is this different from an ordered collection, such as list or vector?

Comment: @Kaz Yes, you are right, it's not a tree, it's a hashtable, or any key-value pair collection. I describe it as tree because I think there may be some methods or algorithms for tree that can be used here.

Comment: You are probably incorrect. The structure you have in fact is a set, because it is unordered, and the similarity metric (however you define it) is a set operation. Tree operations are unlikely to shed light on set operations. The lack of order is important because it means two of these objects should be similar if they have the same contents, without regard for any order.

Comment: Ah yes, collaborative filtering.

Comment: @Kaz The weight is only used when I treat the categories like a tree to calculate the similarity, besides that, the weight is not necessary. Here is my thought: for example, in stackoverflow, if we check the tags in the user page, it shows like "c#*180,java*123,php*210...", every person gets a different result. So we can calculate the similarity of two persons based on the tags information and the amount of questions under the tag, someone may have totally different tags, someone may have the same tags with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using set operations.

> I once implemented such a similarity metric in the Meta-CVS software, years ago. This was used to identify renamed files when importing snapshots to a branch. Of course, files can be renamed and edited between baselines, which means you cannot perform exact comparisons. But I digress.

**Jaccard Index**[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

First of all, two users can have completely different interests in books. Or they can have completely the same interest.

What you can do is compute the size of their combined set of interests, and represent that part they have in common as a fraction of the overall size.

Suppose that the interests sets were not weighted, but simply sets categories without an associated weight.  Similarity could then be expressed as the number of categories that the two users have in common, divided by the total number of categories. That is to say, the cardinality of the set intersection, divided by the cardinality of the set union.

If weights are involved, you have to work them in somehow. Perhaps calculate the total weight of the set intersection by the total weight of the union (watching out for division by zero).

As you can see, this metric yields 0.0 if the users have no categories in common, and 1.0 if they are interested in matching categories (regardless of the weight), so it is viable.

**Cosine Similarity**[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

Another way to define the similarity would be to treat this as a vector dot product (correlation).  Firstly, determine all of the categories that exist between the two users. Form a vector, for each of the two users, in which the weight of every category is present (as a zero, if the user doesn't have that category in his interest set).

Then you can calculate similarity by taking the dot product of these vectors, and dividing it by the product of their lengths:  (A . B) / |A||B|

The length of a vector is the square root of the sum of the squares of the weights. (Again, watching out for division by zero.)

Under this similarity metric, if the users have no categories in common, the two vectors are perpendicular, and their dot product is zero. This metric is basically the cosine of the angle between the two vectors. The closer the cosine is to one, the more parallel the vectors are (users's interests are "aligned in the same direction").

Hope this gives you some ideas; but as you can see, this is open-ended.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, it's glad to talk with you.